# Stop IIS From Reloading Web.Config File

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

My organization runs a rather complex application with a web-based front end. I'm being told that one of our security products (unknown which one yet) is reading the web.config file and apparently the simple reading of the config file is enough to trigger IIS to think the web.config file changed.

This causes a reload of the app pool and a loss of session state which causes users to lose all of their data and get "kicked out".

How can I prevent this short of adding exclusions to our scanning software? I realize that's an option, but I'm hoping for one where I'm not having to make exceptions to security systems. To be clear I don't want to hear/see an answer saying "Just add it to the exception for your scanning software". I'm wanting to know of alternatives first.

Answer (score 1):

In IIS, you have the ability to disable the automatic App Pool recycling when the web.config changes. To do this, go to the Application Pools listing, right-click the App Pool in question, select "Advanced Settings", then all the way at the bottom, in the "Recycling" section, set "Disable Recycling for Configuration Changes" to True.

That being said, reading the configuration file really shouldn't trigger a recycle. Is it updating the Modified timestamp?

Because of the problem you're having, I strongly recommend that you enable event logging for app pool recycles for this app pool, then hopefully you can try to correlate the recycle times with when your security scans run to verify your hypothesis. In the Advanced Settings for the App Pool, under the "Recycling" section, set everything under "Generate Recycle Event Log Entry" to True. The recycle events should show up in the Application log.

Hmm... This wasn't an April Fools joke, was it?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the web.config CANNOT trigger the app pool recycling by design. Are you sure that your "scanning software" is not editing the file?